# Diseño web HTML y CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Alguien me puede ayudar con css. He tratado de hacer este diseño y no me sale.
por ejemplo:
-Al alinear a la izquierda el titulo con el texto no me deja, el titulo se me ubica solo a lado del texto.
-quiero hacer ese hover. al pasar el mouse/raton se pinte de rojo solo el icono.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes publicar tu código por favor?

Comment: Realiza el recorrido y mira como preguntar

Comment: Sin ver el código de lo que estás intentando hacer, todas las respuestas que recibas serán opiniones sobre como lograr lo que muestras en la imagen. Si deseas resolver el problema de tú implementación, debes mostrar el código de la misma. Saludos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para ser mas especifico y te pueda ser útil, sube tu html y css.
Por el momento hice una prueba que como dices en tu comentario puede servirte el hover y la alineación del texto.
Puede tomar lo que te sirva de esta implementación, pero no te quedes con eso siempre se puede hacer mejor.

```css
.fx-sb{
display:flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.fx-cv-ch{
 display:flex;
 align-content: center;
 justify-content: center;
}


.fx-cv{
 display:flex;
 align-content: center;
 }

.list-container{
 padding: 2%;
}

.item-col{
 margin: 8px;
}

.icon-leading{
 border: 2px #E74C3C solid;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
}


.icon-leading:hover{
 background-color: #E74C3C;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <div class="fx-sb">
    
    <div style="display: flex">
      
      <div class="fx-cv-ch icon-leading" style="margin-right: 20px;">
        <img src="https://freepngimg.com/thumb/logo/62837-instagram-icons-photography-computer-logo-icon.png" heigth="36px" width="36px" style="object-fit: contain">
      </div>
      
      <div>
       <strong>EASY TRIP PLANNING</strong>
       <div style="color: #99A3A4; margin-top:8px;">Este es un mensaje generico sin sentido </div>
      </div>
      
    </div> 
    
      <div style="display: flex">
      
      <div class="fx-cv-ch icon-leading" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <img src="https://freepngimg.com/thumb/logo/62837-instagram-icons-photography-computer-logo-icon.png" heigth="36px" width="36px" style="object-fit: contain">
      </div>
      
      <div>
       <strong>EASY TRIP PLANNING</strong>
       <div style="color: #99A3A4; margin-top:5px;">Este es un mensaje generico sin sentido </div>
      </div>
      
    </div> 
    
     
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Una respuesta que solo muestra código se considera de baja calidad. Por otro lado, no debemos responder preguntas que no muestren el código claramente para ver cuál es el error. Te sugiero leer [answer]. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu respuesta, puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos

Answer (score -2):

Hay muchas soluciones para un problema, la que yo usaría seria lo siguiente:

```
<html>  
<body>
<style>
    table{
        width:70%;
        margin-left:15%;
        text-align:left;
    }
    .category{
        display:flex;
        position:relative;
    }
    .icon{
        margin-right:30px;
    }
    .icon:hover{
        margin-right:30px;
        background:red;
    }
    .icon img{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:50%;
        margin-bottom:50%;
    }
    .description{
        position:inherit;
        margin:0;
    }
    
</style>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="category">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/128933/isolated/preview/b54944f7322722034cfda55e601b4f8d-travel-bus-round-icon-by-vexels.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h1 class="header">TRANSPORTATION</h1>
                        <p class="description">Alguna descripcion para la categoria</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="category">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/128933/isolated/preview/b54944f7322722034cfda55e601b4f8d-travel-bus-round-icon-by-vexels.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h1 class="header">TRANSPORTATION</h1>
                        <p class="description">Alguna descripcion para la categoria</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Si te das cuenta he usado tablas y simples etiquetas "div".

Comment: Exacto, hay muchas soluciones y opiniones al respecto, porque el OP no ha mostrado su código y así todas las respuestas serán opiniones sobre como lograr algo. Te sugiero evitar responder preguntas de esta naturaleza, que al final se basan en opiniones. Saludos